# How does Enumerable#sort_by method work?

Tags: ruby, hashmap

Can anyone clear up how this works?

```
frequencies = frequencies.sort_by { |a, b| b}
```

I understand it changes the order the hash is displayed in, but how it does it I have no idea.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: look here - http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by

Comment: `sort_by` uses a technique made popular in Perl by Randal Schwartz, often called a "[Schwartzian Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform)". It precomputes an intermediate value, which is tied to the actual value, and the intermediate value is used for the sort. It's faster than a normal `sort` if there is any calculation needed, especially when dealing with complex objects. For simple objects, like integers and characters and strings, a `sort` will usually walk away from `sort_by` speed-wise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Enumerable#sort_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) sorts based on the return value of the given block.
From your example, `frequencies` seems like a Hash.

Here is an example of sort_by on a Hash

```
 h = {:a => 2, :b => 1, :c => 4}
 #=> {:a=>2, :b=>1, :c=>4}

 h.sort_by {|k, v| v}
 #=> [[:b, 1], [:a, 2], [:c, 4]]
```